# Read CSV files and Report creation in XLSX

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, file

Overview:
THIS PROGRAM/FUNCTION READS ALL - INDIVIDUAL METRICS FILES AND CREATES A EXCEL REPORT WITH ALL METRICS.

```
import glob, os, sys
import csv          
import xlsxwriter

from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook


#Output file name and location 

#format for header object.


# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_number, value in enumerate(f3.columns.values):
    worksheet_object.write(0, col_number + 1, value,
                           header_format_object)

writer_object.save()
```

---

---

Output in Terminal (Success)

```
PS C:\Users\Python-1> &
```

---

Actual output of file in Folder:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Cobol\Outputs
```

---

Actual Output in XLSX file

---

Problem: Results are good, however the S.No Column in XLSX file [number of programs, starts with zero instead of 1]

```
S.No

0
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a reindex?

Set the index before write the csv.
For example:

```
f3.index = np.arange(1, len(f3) + 1)
```